# unix: execute gnuplut in different directories using find | xargs

Tags: unix, find, xargs

I'm pretty new to using the shell. I have many gnuplot scripts in subdirectories. These include relative paths of the input files. So to execute them in the right way I have to go to the parent directory of the script and then execute it. Is there a way to do this with a find | xargs combination?

```
find . -name "*gpf" | xargs -i{} dirname {}
```

is something that I found so far. But I don't know how to go now to the parent directory and then exegute gnuplot right there. Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks.

Edit: Anyone else having any ideas that could help me with this issue? Would really help me a lot! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute gnuplot with the `-exec` option of `find`:

`find . -name "*.gpf" -exec gnuplot \{\} \;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I want. What you recommended will execute the gnuplot scripts in the current directory. But this doesn't get the job done, because I use relative paths in my scripts and so gnuplot will try to find the input files relative from the current directory and not relative from the directory where the script lies. So gnuplot should be executed in the subdirectories where the scripts are that I found with the find command.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
find . -name "*gpf" | parallel "cd {//};gnuplot {/}"
```

Learn more about GNU Parallel: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

10 second installation:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```